# How to navigate one html page to another html page using java script?

Tags: javascript, html

How to navigate one html page to another html page

I am trying below code but this is not working

below is my html code

```
<form name="form"  class="loginform">
                    <div style="padding:5px;">
                        <input id="text" type="text" name="uname" class="uname" placeholder="Username">
                    </div>
                    <div style="padding:5px;">
                        <input type="password" name="password" class="password" placeholder="Password">
                        <br/>
                    </div>
                    <div style="padding:5px;">
                        <!--<input type="submit" class="buttonCol" value="Logn in" onclick="callMe();" />-->
                        <button onClick="callMe();" value="Logn in"  class="buttonCol">Logn in</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="notNumber">
                        Not a member yet?&nbsp; <a href="" class="to_register" style="color:red;">Join us</a>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

below is my js code

```
  function callMe() {
       location.href = "moviebooking.html";
   }
```

Comment: if you are not using any backend why you need javascript put an anchor tag href

Comment: Your code as shown works correctly; you must have some other problem not included here.  Have you checked your console log for errors?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<button onClick="callMe();" value="Logn in" id="login" 
 class="buttonCol">Logn in</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("login").onclick = function () {
    location.href = "moviebooking.html";
};
</script>
```